# How to abstract link_tos for nested resources on multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested resource in a Rails 3.2 app.

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

resources locations do
  resources :posts
end

resources categories 
  resources :posts
end
```

In a shared sidebar module displayed on User, Location and Category show pages I have a link to the nested resource

```
<% if controller.class == UsersController %>
  <%= link_to "Posts", user_posts_path(@user) %>
<% elsif controller.class == LocationsController %>
  <%= link_to "Posts", location_posts_path(@location) %>
<% elsif controller.class == CategoriesController %>
  <%= link_to "Posts", category_posts_path(@category) %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a clever way to DRY this up? I'm thinking something like `<%= link_to "Posts", controller_name_posts_path(@current_object) %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as clever as that but I'd simplify as a first step by defining @resource_path (actually I'd probably expose a method) in each controller so that the view template is simplified to something like

```
<%= link_to "Posts", @resource_path %>
```

In the controller action - something like:

```
@resource_path = user_posts_path(@user)
```

or similar

Comment: Great! I knew I was overlooking something. Thank you.

Comment: NP :-) I usually find that moving logic out of the view whenever possible results in a win most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Using [content_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for)(or just provide) should do the trick as well.

Without touching your controller add call to **content_for** at the top of your view show files:

example for users/show:

```
<% content_for :resource_path, user_posts_path(@user) %>
```

In your shared sidebar module change your block of code to:

```
<%= link_to "Posts", yield :resource_path %>
```